# Simulating power failure in a docker container

Tags: docker

I am testing how an application (influxDB) handles a power failure as I have a problem in production with it. Currently, I have an embedded linux device that has the problematic software and to recreate the issue I must connect to the embedded device, make it write to influx DB and unplug it while it is writing. All of that is really tedious because I must get up to another room and unplug the device guessing the time. Than again connect to it, after it boots... This is slow and may harm my only device I have with me (home office).

Instead of using the physical embedded linux device where I need to unplug the device manually I want to simplify the process with docker. With docker I can simulate the process locally on my ARM PC up until the power failure (virtual unplugging, I do not want to unplug my PC). Is there a way to do it in docker?

I tried shutting down the docker, but I am not sure it recreates the sudden lost of power to the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it in docker?

No, you can't simulate a "power failure" in docker, as the kernel is shared. You might be interested in real virtualization.

Comment: Interesting. Could you elaborate on what the "kernel is shared" entails? (I guess that's where emergency power management happens so it could simply not be separated from host power management?)

Comment: I do not understand what to elaborate. Docker starts just a process that runs and uses the same kernel as the host. All the virtualization is done within the kernel, that is shared. `hat's where emergency power management happens` I do not understand. Process management is nowhere near hardware error and unflushed I/O buffers. "Power management" is just setting specific CPU registers, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: why does the kernel being shared prevent the simulation of a power failure?

Comment: Because kernel makes sure that I/O buffers are properly flushed to disc. In case of power failure they are not - application may think they were written, when in fact they are in memory and lost on power failure. And power failure can cause partial writes. Much depends on the underlying file system, and the file system driver is (most usually) part of the kernel. This sounds crucial in testing something like consistency of a database.

Comment: great, that does clarify it. care to add it to your answer? that was my goal, to flesh out the answer, since "it's impossible because I say so" was rather vague.

Answer (score 2):

- You can try `docker container kill`
  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_kill/
- Docker kill commands instantly stop the container without taking any time. It is similar to the docker stop command, it just sends a SIGKILL signal to the running container process.

`docker container kill [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]`
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/

- Instead of using Docker, you may use VirtualBox and select the option to force power off the virtual machine. This should be equivalent to unplugging the power cord from a physical machine.